# Remove strings found in vector 1, from vector 2

Tags: r, gsub, sapply

I have these two vectors:

```
sample1 <- c(".aaa", ".aarp", ".abb", ".abbott", ".abogado")
sample2 <- c("try1.aarp", "www.tryagain.aaa", "255.255.255.255", "onemoretry.abb.abogado")
```

I am trying to remove sample1 strings that are found in sample2. The closest I got is by iterating using `sapply`, which gave me this:

```
 sapply(sample1, function(i)gsub(i, "", sample2))

     .aaa                     .aarp                    .abb                 .abbott                  .abogado          
[1,] "try1.aarp"              "try1"                   "try1.aarp"          "try1.aarp"              "try1.aarp"       
[2,] "www.tryagain"           "www.tryagain.aaa"       "www.tryagain.aaa"   "www.tryagain.aaa"       "www.tryagain.aaa"
[3,] "255.255.255.255"        "255.255.255.255"        "255.255.255.255"    "255.255.255.255"        "255.255.255.255" 
[4,] "onemoretry.abb.abogado" "onemoretry.abb.abogado" "onemoretry.abogado" "onemoretry.abb.abogado" "onemoretry.abb"
```

Of course the expected output should be

```
[1] "www.tryagain"    "try1"            "onemoretry"      "255.255.255.255"
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
sample1 <- c(".aaa", ".aarp", ".abb", ".abbott", ".abogado")
sample2 <- c("try1.aarp", "www.tryagain.aaa", "255.255.255.255", "onemoretry.abb.abogado")
paste0("(",paste(sub("\\.", "\\\\.", sample1), collapse="|"),")\\b")
# [1] "(\\.aaa|\\.aarp|\\.abb|\\.abbott|\\.abogado)\\b"
gsub(paste0("(",paste(sub("\\.", "\\\\.", sample1), collapse="|"),")\\b"), "", sample2)
# [1] "try1"            "www.tryagain"    "255.255.255.255" "onemoretry"
```

*Explanation:*

- `sub("\\.", "\\\\.", sample1)` escapes all the dots. Since dots are special chars in regex.
- `paste(sub("\\.", "\\\\.", sample1), collapse="|")` combines all the elements with `|` as delimiter.
- `paste0("(",paste(sub("\\.", "\\\\.", sample1), collapse="|"),")\\b")` creates a regex like all the elements present inside a capturing group followed by a word boundary. `\\b` is a much needed one here . So that it would do an exact word match.

Comment: could you explain it a little please?

Comment: I would have used `[.]` to remove the special meaning instead of `\\\\.` (more readable in resulting regex IMHO)

Comment: Side Note: My full `sample1` has 1199 elements. Running the regex, an error occurred,  (`Error in gsub(paste0("(", paste(sub("\\.", "\\\\.", sample1), collapse = "|"),  : 
  assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 634`) so I split `sample1` into two vectors; vector1 with 629 elements and vector2 with the remaining 570.

Answer (score 1):

We can `paste` the 'sample1' elements together, use that as the `pattern` argument in `gsub`, replace it with `''`.

```
gsub(paste(sample1, collapse='|'), '', sample2)
#[1] "try1"            "www.tryagain"    "255.255.255.255" "onemoretry"
```

Or use `mgsub`

```
library(qdap)
mgsub(sample1, '', sample2)
#[1] "try1"            "www.tryagain"    "255.255.255.255" "onemoretry"
```