# Extract all characters to the right of a list of possible characters

Tags: r, string, extract

I have a series of strings in a dataframe like the ones below:

```
item_time<-c("pink dress july noon", "shirt early september morning", "purple dress 
april", "tall purple shoes february")
```

And I want to extract all the characters to the right of a list of possible characters like these:

```
item<-c("pink dress","shirt","purple dress", "tall purple shoes")
```

The result I want would look like this:

```
[1] july noon
[2] early september morning
[3] april
[4] february
```

I can't separate them by spaces as there are varying number of words in the time and item lists. I also don't have a symbol that separates them. I feel that there should be a quite simple and elegant way of solving this but I can't figure it out.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872957/remove-strings-found-in-vector-1-from-vector-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `sub` and a regular expression.

```
Pat = paste0("(.*)(", paste0(item, collapse="|"), ")(.*)")
sub(Pat, "\\3", item_time)
[1] " july noon"               " early september morning"
[3] " april"                   " february"
```

**Details:**   The pattern that is created is:

```
Pat
[1] "(.*)(pink dress|shirt|purple dress|tall purple shoes)(.*)"
```

The middle part `"(.*)(pink dress|shirt|purple dress|tall purple shoes)` matche4s any one of your patterns.  The first `(.*)` matches anything before the pattern. The second `(.*)` matches anything after the pattern.  The `sub` statement then replaces the whole string with just the part after the pattern match.

Comment: Can simplify to: `Pat = paste0(".*(", paste0(item, collapse="|"), ")\\s+");sub(Pat, "", item_time)`

Comment: I get an error message that  "pattern and replacement vectors must be the same length" ...thank you!

Comment: I do not get that error. Which statement gave you that error?

Comment: sub(Pat, "\\3", item_time)

Comment: What value do you have for `Pat`?

Comment: I solved it! one more question: How can I make the output be a data.table? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: `DT = data.table(time=sub(Pat, "\\2", item_time))`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using mapply

```
mapply(gsub,pattern=item,replacement='',x=item_time)
```

If you also want to remove the space between `item` and the right part of `item_time`, you can instead use:

```
mapply(gsub,pattern=paste0(item,' '),replacement='',x=item_time)
```

Comment: or perhaps `trimws(mapply(gsub, item, '', item_time, fixed = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `stringr::str_replace(string, pattern, replacement)`, which has the advantage that it is vectorised over both `string` and `pattern` (and `replacement` as well).

```
trimws(stringr::str_replace(item_time, item, ""))
#[1] "july noon"               "early september morning"
#[3] "april"                   "february"
```

`trimws` removes the leading whitespace.

Note that this requires `item_time` and `item` to have pairwise matching entries.