# substitute words in a column

Tags: r

```
a <- data.frame(text = c("hello <firstname> what do you wish to order today?", "I don't understand this. Can you repeat"))
```

I want to substitute - "hello " and "Can you repeat" with blank so that I get remaining part of text.

How do I give specific list of words that I want to substitute with blank.
Here specific word is "hello  and "can you repeat". Like this , there are many words in my dataframe.

Expected output in dataframe:

> ```
> [1] what do you wish to order today?
>
> [2] I don't understand this.
> ```

Comment: Please fix your example. It throws error. Maybe you are looking for this `trimws(gsub('hello|can you repeat', '', tolower(a$text)))` though I am not sure what happened to `<firstname>`

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872957/remove-strings-found-in-vector-1-from-vector-2)

Answer (score 2):

One way with `gsub`:

```
#add the words to remove in an atomic vector
to_remove <- c('hello', 'Can you repeat')
#paste the words together and remove with gsub
gsub(paste(to_remove, collapse = '|'), ' ', a$text)
#[1] "  <firstname> what do you wish to order today?"
#[2] "I don't understand this.  "
```

As per @Sotos comment, when dealing with text, it is probably a good idea to lower case the text and get rid of trailing spaces:

```
trimws(paste(to_remove, collapse = '|'), '', tolower(a$text)))
```

Comment: couple of suggestions. It is probably better to keep/convert everything to lower case. Also you can wrap everything in `trimws` to get rid of leading/trailing spaces - See my comment above

Comment: @Sotos Yeah I agree to both. This is the safest technique when dealing with text. I guess I wanted to show the answer only to what the OP has asked. I ll add.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called gsub which you can use. It looks at string given a pattern then replaces with the desired output.

```
gsub(pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
    fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)
```

Example:

```
gsub("hello", "", a$text)
```

Then if you like, you can save the output to as a new column or new variable.

There are some additional things with gsub being case sensitive and what not, but those can be found [here](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php). This also has some additional examples.

Answer (score 0):

The `gsub` solutions work as well, here is a tidyverse solution.

```
require(tidyverse)
b <- a %>% mutate(
    text_new = str_remove_all(text, c("hello <firstname>", "Can you repeat"))
  )
b
```